# BigQuery Result save as google sheets through api

Tags: google-bigquery, google-sheets-api

In Google BigQuery WebUI, it shows query result screen after executing a query, and it shows the button of "Save as Google Sheets".  I like this feature but would like to automate this, is there such function through the REST API that I could do?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this can be done through the REST API, but an alternative solution could be using [OWOX BI BigQuery reports](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/owox-bi-bigquery-reports/fepofngogkjnejgcbdmmkddnpeojbbin), a Google Sheets add-on that lets you query BQ data directly from Google Sheets (and schedule reports).

Answer (score 3):

It doesn’t seem like there is a straightforward way to do this directly with the BigQuery API. There are few workarounds for this though:

1. You can use the BigQuery API [to query your data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) and then the [GoogleSheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) to upload it to Google Sheets.
2. You can use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/). If you go to [this link](https://script.google.com/), you click on “New Script”, you can run the code below. You can adapt this to your needs. You can also add a trigger to run the script every hour/minute …

Here the code snippet [from this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery):

```
function runQuery() {
  // Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google
  // Cloud Platform project.
  var projectId = 'XXXXXXXX';

  var request = {
    query: 'SELECT TOP(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count ' +
      'FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;'
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }

  // Get all the rows of results.
  var rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }

  if (rows) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('BiqQuery Results');
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

    // Append the headers.
    var headers = queryResults.schema.fields.map(function(field) {
      return field.name;
    });
    sheet.appendRow(headers);

    // Append the results.
    var data = new Array(rows.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cols = rows[i].f;
      data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
      }
    }
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(data);

    Logger.log('Results spreadsheet created: %s',
        spreadsheet.getUrl());
  } else {
    Logger.log('No rows returned.');
  }
}
```